# SQL Server Maintenance Plan in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

It happens that I need to enter Maintenance Plan Wizard and at the moment of executing it I get the following error. It asks me to reinstall SQL Server Management Studio, I do it and I still get the error. Most likely I would have to reinstall the SQL Server but I can not because I do not have the installation ISO because it is paid SQL.

What can I do in this case?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYeCH.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: have you restarted the instance after you installed the tools?

Comment: The error is not asking you to reinstall SSMS. The error suggests SSIS is not installed on the database server. That said, [Ola Halengren's popular T-SQL based maintenance solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/) is often used instead of SSIS-based maintenance plans. This avoids the dependency on SSIS.